# Is there any multimap with different values of different object for one key in java-redis?

Tags: java, collections, redis, multimap, redisson

My application requires a multivaluemap to store in redis cache with a key having 2 different objects saying object1 and object2. Map can return all the values or a single value based on type parameter as in get(key, type).
Couldn't find such feature in either reddison or jedis. Is there any other library providing this data structure or I would have to implement my own?

Comment: You would have to implement your own.

Comment: Did you try Redisson's Multimap object https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/7.-distributed-collections#72-multimap ?

Comment: yes I saw redisson's multimap. they having function for multiple value of same object. but i need 2 different types of object for one key.

Comment: @sazzad can you suggest me how to implement?

Comment: @J.gokul Sorry man. I feel, suggestion post would be too large and the number of discussions would be too many which would be beyond the scope of this platform.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no this kind of data structure in Redis, you have to do a little design by yourself, using extra keys to store extra information.